# Rails throws an exception while model interacts with the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below is my controller code :

```
 render json: {}, status: :bad_request and return if params[:service].nil?
 service = Service.find_by_name(params[:service])
 certification = Certification.find_by_build(params[:version])
 join_table = service.certifications.select('id','build','is_certified').where(:build=>certification.build,:service_id=>service.id)
 render json: join_table.to_json, status: :ok
```

---

```
Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `to_i' for #<Array:0x007fec563f7bf0>
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/content_length.rb:17:in `call'
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thin-1.6.3/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-1.5.3/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    /Users/pnagashr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    bin/rails:8:in `require'
    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: include the code that's having the problem, and format this for readability.

Comment: show the code where the "to_i" function is being called.

Comment: to_i is not being called me . Looks like its the framework . I am guessing its the render method which calls to_i

Comment: `.where` returns an array of records. If you are looking to emit a single record use `.find_by(build: certification.build)` (you don't need the service id since you are basing the query off the relation)